# Convert String into Formula with external reference

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to convert a cellvalue (string) to a formula. It works fine when the cellvalue has something like this: A1+B1.
But when the cellvalue (string) has a reference to an other workbook, then got #Value! error in the cell (see example below in C2). Does anybody know why?

[image]

```
Sub Test()
'Application.Volatile

Dim s As String

's = "=" & Range("C1").Value
s = Range("C1").Value

Range("D1") = Application.Evaluate(s)
'Range("D1").Formula = Application.Evaluate(s)

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the other file open?

Comment: Yes or no. It makes no difference.

Comment: Works fine for me.  If you add `=` in C2 does the formula evaluate correctly?

Comment: If I put it manualy "=" then yes, the formula works fine

Answer (score 0):

### Evaluate Formula in Excel

- Since you have `Application.Volatile` (although out-commented) in your procedure, I am assuming you are trying to create a function to evaluate one cell's formula.
- This is a basic example which you could build on.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function evalFormula(FormulaCell As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    With FormulaCell.Cells(1)
        If Len(.Value) > 0 Then
            evalFormula = Application.Evaluate(.Value)
        Else
            evalFormula = ""
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

- With your example data, you could use this function in `Excel` in e.g. cell `D1`:

  ```
  =evalFormula(C1)
  =IFERROR(evalFormula(C1),"")
  ```

  and copy down.
- Note that this evaluation is performed in `VBA` (not `Excel`) so you will have to use the comma (`,`) in the 'formula strings', although your list separator (like in my case) may be the semi-colon (`;`).
- Also using `Application.Volatile` may help you in one case, but not in another one i.e. if you use it, then when you close an external workbook the retrieved value will be there only until the worksheet is recalculated. If you don't use it, the retrieved values may be there all the time if you do not change the values in the source cells, but values may not update correctly. Test this to find out which is more 'convenient' in your case.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work, tried all possibilities. What I do believe: Wenn I manually put in front of the cellvalue a "=" then it perfectly worked. It needs some seconds to get the value from the other workbook (when the wb not opend a little bit more). But with my and your solution, the valuation has been calculated within milliseconds. It looks like for me that one step between is missing... something like: open first the workbook, get the connection and than start to evaluate the value.